# Program not running / getting to debug point

Tags: c#, parsing, visual-studio-2015

I've been getting a lot of help here which I appreciate.  I can't seem to get my simple text parser to work, though.  Any help pointing me to my errors would be appreciated.

My Program.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Cawk
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Cawk.Execute(File.OpenText(@"C:\Temp\test.txt"));
        }
    }
}
```

From there I'm trying to just pass a simple text file to my parser, but I have a console debug line in the beginning and it's never being written, nor do I get any output from the program.

Cawk.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Cawk
    {
    public static class Cawk
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> Execute(StreamReader input)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            Console.WriteLine("Test output from Cawk");
            string line;
            //string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            //read all rows
            while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

            // trim trailing spaces
            //line = line.Trim();

//[and so on until the line is parsed and written to the console]
```

I never get "Test output from Cawk" though.  I'm saving it, building it, and then running the application from a command prompt.  Why do I never get to the Console.Writeline in Cawk?

Thanks all.

Comment: WHat does happen when you run it?

Comment: If you have a `yield` in your `Execute`, then it will not be "run" until you start to enumerate on it (but you cut off the code before we can see this).

Comment: Please provide entire code of your `Execute` method. Especially that part where you `return` or `yield` something.

Answer (score 3):

Well of course you don't, `Execute` returns an enumerable which you ignore. Enumerables don't actually execute the code in them until they are enumerated.

For example, a fix would be:

```
foreach(Cawk.Execute(File.OpenText(@"C:\Temp\test.txt")));
```

Which I hope is a large enough clue that there's something seriously wrong with your architecture.

Comment: How do you know if the code shown is an iterator? I don't see any `yield`s. Maybe it's really returning an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` at the end.

Comment: No, pretty sure that is not how it works for a function that returns an `IEnumerable` (since I just tested this myself).

Comment: You are free to think what you want, of course. However based on the problem he's describing and the fact that the only dictionary he shows is `row` and the return type is `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` I bet his last line is `yield return row;`

Comment: Yes, if he has a `yield`.

Comment: I agree that this *could* explain the problem, but I think it would fit better as a comment as there's a lot of uncertainty. This answer should also at least mention iterators--it could mislead someone to think that all functions that return IEnumerables are "magic" in this way.

Comment: I'm not uncertain, it's called deductive reasoning.